# Finder got an error: Can’t get button returned of Finder window id 12575

Tags: macos, applescript

The AppleScript app that I have been working on is giving me the error "Finder got an error: Can’t get button returned of Finder window id 12575." This is happening whenever I try to open a finder window from my app.  Here is the main part of the app where this error is occurring:

`display dialog "What would you like to do?
    Sleep = Go to sleep
    Finder = Open Finder
    Time = Display current time and date
    2048 = Play 2048
    Quit = Quit application" default answer "" with title "Control panel"
if the text returned of the result is "Sleep" then
    tell application "System Events" to sleep
    display dialog "Hello, welcome back!" buttons {"Thank you!"} default button 1
    return
else if the text returned of the result is "Finder" then
    tell application "Finder" to make new Finder window
else if the text returned of the result is "Time" then
    set a to (current date) as list
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
    set a to a as text
    display dialog a buttons {"OK"} default button 1
else if the text returned of the result is "Quit" then
    return
else if the text returned of the result is "2048" then
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script "/Users/student/Documents/2048.sh"
        activate
    end tell
    return
else
    display dialog "Invalid response" with title "Invalid response" buttons {"Go back", "Quit"} default button 1
end if
if the button returned of the result is "Go back" then
    display dialog "What would you like to do?
    Sleep = Go to sleep
    Finder = Open Finder
    Time = Display current time and date
    2048 = Play 2048
    Quit = Quit application" default answer "" with title "Control panel"
else
    return
end if
if the text returned of the result is "Sleep" then
    tell application "System Events" to sleep
    display dialog "Hello, welcome back!" buttons {"Thank you!"} default button 1
    return
else if the text returned of the result is "Finder" then
    tell application "Finder" to make new Finder window
    return
else if the text returned of the result is "Time" then
    set a to (current date) as list
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
    set a to a as text
    display dialog a buttons {"OK"} default button 1
else if the text returned of the result is "Quit" then
    return
else if the text returned of the result is "2048" then
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script "/Users/student/Documents/2048.sh"
        activate
    end tell
    return
end if`

Answer (score 1):

Quote from ASLG:

> "When a statement is executed, AppleScript stores the resulting value, if any, in the predefined property result. The value remains there until another statement is executed that generates a value. Until a statement that yields a result is executed, the value of result is undefined. You can examine the result in Script Editor by looking in the Result pane of the script window."

the result property is wrongly set by the previous statement that's been executed `tell application "Finder" to make new finder window` My advise to you (any scripter) is that when you want the result of an statement to use later in the code than the next line you should use variables. Here and example how to use variables.

```
set dialogResult to display dialog "What would you like to do?" default answer "Continue"

if button returned of dialogResult is not "OK" then
    return false
end if

if text returned of dialogResult is not "Continue" then
    return false
end if

return true
```